# Using a VS Macro for setting PreprocessorDefinitions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, macros, msbuild

so i want to set proprocessor definitions by using Visual Studio macros like this:

```
<PreprocessorDefinitions>$(ProjectName)_DEFINE</PreprocessorDefinitions>
```

so I can use it in a src file like that:

```
#ifdef MyProjectName_DEFINE
#define helloWorld
#endif
```

plz help me. i could not find anything in the web except something with the /D parameter, so i tried: /D$(ProjectName)_EXPORT but it still didnt work :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both setting `PreprocessorDefinitions` and using the `/D` option should work fine, but it's hard to tell why they do not for your case. Possibly you are setting the options for a different build configuration than the one you are using, or you have a typo somewhere.

For example: right-click a project in VS, select correct *Configuration* and *Platform* then go to *Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor* and enter

```
%(PreProcessorDefinitions);$(ProjectName)_DEFINED
```

as the value for *Preprocessor Definitions*

Now if your project is named *MyProject* then the preprocessor symbol `MyProject_DEFINED` will be defined. Note the use of `%(PreProcessorDefinitions)` which is to make sure definitions set earlier in the build process are inherited.
If you open the project in a text editor it will look like this (here showing the part for Debug|Win32 builds):

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
  <ClCompile>
    <PreProcessorDefinitions>%(PreProcessorDefinitions);$(ProjectName)_DEFINED</PreProcessorDefinitions>
  </ClCompile>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

If you need the definition for every platform/configuration, copy/paste the above and remove the `Condition` part.

Comment: somehow it worked when i wrote it like you did! thanks a lot!!